# BadMethodCallException : Call to undefined method App\User::factory()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-8

tengan buen día espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.

Al ejecutar las migraciones de un proyecto en `Laravel 6.20` con sus respectivos seeders me arroja el siguiente error

```
BadMethodCallException  : Call to undefined method App\User::factory()

    46|      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
    47|      */
    48|     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
    49|     {
  > 50|         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    51|             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
    52|         ));
    53|     }
    54| }
```

Mi modelo `User` esta por defecto como viene con el propio laravel y solo le agregue un campo más a su migración

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Así se ve mi **Factory** `UserFactory.php`

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@example.com',
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => bcrypt('contraseña'),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Y el **Seeder** `DatabasesSeeder.php`

Espero puedan ayudarme, no entiendo porque la variable $factory es undefined, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error proviene de la sintaxis que estás tratando de emplear.

Debes pasar en tu clase Seeder de esto:

```
User::factory().......
```

A esto:

```
factory(User::class)->create();
```

- [Aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/seeding#using-model-factories) puedes leer sobre la sintaxis válida en el caso de Laravel 6.

Ya que el código que tratas de usar es parte de las características propias de [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases) donde:

- Se puede usar los factories de la siguiente manera:

  ```
  User::factory()->count(numero)->create();
  ```

Gracias al *trait* **`HasFactory`** que en instalaciones de Laravel 8 o superior, viene en la ruta: `app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory`

Comment: Si, efectivamente @BetaM ese era mi error, por suerte ayer pude notarlo a tiempo, de igual manera muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @JosbertMuria recuerda marcar como respuesta con el check